# Extract files from Windows floppy writer exe

Tags: archiving, extract, floppy

I have some files that are `PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`, according to `file`, and only want me to "insert a floppy" when run.

Is there some way to extract the files from them, preferably in Linux? The archive manager does not recognise them.

They are old software installation diskettes, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the disk images are uncompressed in the exe file it would be easy to loop mount them with the correct offset. This is an example with some HP bios boot disk writer that makes a FreeDOS bootdisk. First open the file in hexedit:

```
hexedit Floppy.exe
```

and look if you find something that resembles a boot sector of a floppy. For example search for FAT12 (4641543132 in hex):

```
[ctrl]+S 4641543132[Enter]
```

If you are lucky and it finds the start of a floppy image that looks similar to these screenshots, then navigate the cursor to the start code **EB** in `EB 3C 90` and remember the offset it prints in the footer: `--0x6C00/` in this case.

Then mount the image with the correct offset:

```
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=$((16#6C00)) Floppy.exe /mnt
```

[image: bootsector of uncompressed floppy image in .exe file]

Another example of an old floppy bootsector:
[image: older bootsector of a floppy]